# Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 3 found

Tags: flutter

I don't know what seems to be the problem in here. I'm seeking for an answer on this problem it says "Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 3 found." I can't find a solution for this[image]

This is the code of the problem. I just got this one in the tutorial that I'm watching for flutter. Since I'm just new in using flutter, I don't know how to solve it. The error is "

```
SizedBox(
  width: 5,
),
```

"

```
class ProductDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/ProductDetails';

  @override
  _ProductDetailsState createState() => _ProductDetailsState();
}

class _ProductDetailsState extends State<ProductDetails> {
  GlobalKey previewContainer = new GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeState = Provider.of<DarkThemeProvider>(context);
    final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false);
    final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String;
    final cartProvider = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);

    final favsProvider = Provider.of<FavsProvider>(context);
    print('productId $productId');
    final prodAttr = productsData.findById(productId);
    final productsList = productsData.products;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black12),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Image.network(
              prodAttr.imageUrl,
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                const SizedBox(height: 250),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.purple.shade200,
                          onTap: () {},
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.save,
                              size: 23,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.purple.shade200,
                          onTap: () {},
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.share,
                              size: 23,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                              child: Text(
                                prodAttr.title,
                                maxLines: 2,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  // color: Theme.of(context).textSelectionColor,
                                  fontSize: 28.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 8,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'US \$ ${prodAttr.price}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: themeState.darkTheme
                                      ? Theme.of(context).disabledColor
                                      : ColorsConsts.subTitle,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 21.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                      const SizedBox(height: 3.0),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                        child: Divider(
                          thickness: 1,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text(
                          prodAttr.description,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            fontSize: 21.0,
                            color: themeState.darkTheme
                                ? Theme.of(context).disabledColor
                                : ColorsConsts.subTitle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                        child: Divider(
                          thickness: 1,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      _details(themeState.darkTheme, 'Brand: ', prodAttr.brand),
                      _details(themeState.darkTheme, 'Quantity: ',
                          '${prodAttr.quantity}'),
                      _details(themeState.darkTheme, 'Category: ',
                          prodAttr.productCategoryName),
                      _details(themeState.darkTheme, 'Popularity: ',
                          prodAttr.isPopular ? 'Popular' : 'Barely known'),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        thickness: 1,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        height: 1,
                      ),

                      // const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                      Container(
                        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'No reviews yet',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: TextSelectionTheme.of(context).selectionColor,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    fontSize: 21.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'Be the first review!',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  color: themeState.darkTheme
                                      ? Theme.of(context).disabledColor
                                      : ColorsConsts.subTitle,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 70,
                            ),
                            Divider(
                              thickness: 1,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              height: 1,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                // const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                  child: Text(
                    'Suggested products:',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 340,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount:
                    productsList.length < 7 ? productsList.length : 7,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
                      return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                          value: productsList[index], child: FeedProducts());
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0,
                centerTitle: true,
                title: Text(
                  "DETAIL",
                  style:
                  TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  Consumer<FavsProvider>(
                    builder: (_, favs, ch) => Badge(
                      badgeStyle: BadgeStyle(
                        badgeColor: ColorsConsts.cartBadgeColor,
                      ),
                      badgeAnimation: BadgeAnimation.slide(
                        toAnimate: true,
                        animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                      ),
                      position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: 5, end: 7),
                      badgeContent: Text(
                        favs.getFavsItems.length.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          MyAppIcons.wishlist,
                          color: ColorsConsts.favColor,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context)
                              .pushNamed(WishlistScreen.routeName);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Consumer<CartProvider>(
                    builder: (_, cart, ch) => Badge(
                      badgeStyle: BadgeStyle(
                        badgeColor: ColorsConsts.cartBadgeColor,
                      ),
                      badgeAnimation: BadgeAnimation.slide(
                        toAnimate: true,
                        animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                      ),
                      position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: 5, end: 7),
                      badgeContent: Text(
                        cart.getCartItems.length.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          MyAppIcons.cart,
                          color: ColorsConsts.cartColor,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context)
                              .pushNamed(CartScreen.routeName);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Row(children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide.none),
                      color: Colors.redAccent.shade400,
                      onPressed:
                      cartProvider.getCartItems.containsKey(productId)
                          ? () {}
                          : () {
                        cartProvider.addProductToCart(
                            productId,
                            prodAttr.price,
                            prodAttr.title,
                            prodAttr.imageUrl);
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        cartProvider.getCartItems.containsKey(productId)
                            ? 'In cart'
                            : 'Add to Cart'.toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide.none),
                      color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Buy now'.toUpperCase(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                color: TextSelectionTheme.of(context).selectionColor,
                          ),
                           SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.payment,
                            color: Colors.green.shade700,
                            size: 19,
                          ),
                          )],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: themeState.darkTheme
                        ? Theme.of(context).disabledColor
                        : ColorsConsts.subTitle,
                    height: 50,
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: ColorsConsts.favColor,
                      onTap: () {
                        favsProvider.addAndRemoveFromFav(productId,
                            prodAttr.price, prodAttr.title, prodAttr.imageUrl);
                      },
                      child: Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          favsProvider.getFavsItems.containsKey(productId)
                              ? Icons.favorite
                              : MyAppIcons.wishlist,
                          color:
                          favsProvider.getFavsItems.containsKey(productId)
                              ? Colors.red
                              : ColorsConsts.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _details(bool themeState, String title, String info) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 16, right: 16),
      child: Row(
        //  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: TextSelectionTheme.of(context).selectionColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 21.0),
          ),
          Text(
            info,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              fontSize: 20.0,
              color: themeState
                  ? Theme.of(context).disabledColor
                  : ColorsConsts.subTitle,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the SizedBox inside Text Widget just put " ), " before SizedBox widget and it will work fine.

> ```
>   SizedBox(
>              width: 100,
>              child: Row(
>                  children: [
>                         Text(
>                        'test',
>                           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.red),
>                         ),
>                         SizedBox(width: 50,)
>                       ]),
>                     ),
> ```